# Nearest-neighbour surface plot from matlab2tikz fails with colormap

Tags: pgfplots, matlab

I load an external custom colormap with

```
\input{coolwarm_.map}
```

I have a range of complex surface plots created with matlab2tikz which use this colormap and compile successfully. One does not. It fails with this error:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: No such element: \pgfplotsarrayselect257\of{pgfpl@cm@
matlab}.
```

I tried the fix given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65718/error-when-creating-a-surf-plot-with-matlab2tikz) but it does not work.

You can look at the [colormap here](http://pastebin.ca/2459566).

The [working tikzpicture is here.](http://pastebin.ca/2459568)

The [non-working tikzpicture is here.](http://pastebin.ca/2459567)

I am wondering if it has anything to do with the plot type; the one that fails is a nearest neighbour interpolation with some very steep surfaces, the other is a cubic interpolation.

EDIT: Yes, this is a clue to the cause -- the other nearest neighbour surface plot in my collection, produced with MATLAB's `TriScatteredInterp`, produces exactly the same error when using this colormap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a bug in `pgfplots` v1.8 (or earlier). It has already been fixed and will be part of the next stable 1.9.

Pre-release downloads can be retrieved from http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm still puzzled why it happens with the one plot, but not the other, though. What's the nature of the bug? Can you elaborate?

Comment: It is related to rounding/interpolation of color values near the upper end of the color map: there was a defect in a check which manifested itsself only under strange circumstances.

Comment: The prerelease version of pgfplots does indeed correct the problem. Best of all, my other graphics still compile, too ;)